# After changing test case, test case in test run not changed. Does it work as designed?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Add a test case to a test run, then change test cases, e.g., steps, or expected results. But test case in test run displays changed before.

At first, I think it maybe a bug. Discuss with my workmate, he think it right. Test run keep a copy after test case add to run.

Yes, seems reasonable. Does this as designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as designed. TestRun keeps a copy of the TestCase text from the time when TR was created. You see for build 1 I may want a very basic test for say the login screen, but for build 2, 3, etc I want to improve this.

This is why such functionality exists.

In TestRun page there is the Cases -> Update menu which will refresh TestCase text for IDLE entries.

For the ones that have already been executed either change them to IDLE before update or just create a new TestRun.